# AngularJS scope no updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using a button that invokes ***clickLoadMorePosts*** which has two parameters, the important one is the ***date***, this button triggers the function below.

In the response, I'm receiving javascript code that update this ***date*** in the button's parameter and it's updating fine, but when I click again that button, the scope is taking the first date, instead the date i got in the response even when this new date is updated in the html code (I looked through Google chrome inspector).

I think the problem is because $scope is not updating the new content and therefore is not taking the new date.

I also read that I should probably use $apply in some place, but I got an error because $http uses $apply.

Help and insight are appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<span id="loadMorePosts" ng-click="clickLoadMorePosts({{$idAccount}},'{{$date}}')"> Load more content </span>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $http ) {

    $scope.clickLoadMorePosts = function(idAccount, date) {

      $http.post("loadPersonalPosts", {'idAccount': idAccount, 'date': date} )
        .success(function (data) {
            $('#postLoader').append(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            alert("error");
      });
    };
}
```

Comment: You're appending the data to `$('#postLoader')`... what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the response data to a scope variable, in the page, you should use like {$scope.data. date} rather than manipulating the DOM via append.